# Best way to shows string in layout.xml files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm developing apps using Android Studio. In Android Studio I design the interfaces of the app using the build in GUI editor. I'm looking for a way to display "fake" strings values in the layouts in order for me to check if the interface looks correct. However, I don't want these "fake" strings to appear in the app builds. In the app builds (debug/release) I want the edit text fields to be empty, the "fake" string should not be part of the build.
What would be the best way to achieve this? Or is there a better way of working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy. Try with newest Android Studio:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/appVersion"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:textSize="20sp"

         tools:text="Version 1.0" 
     />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And AS will also suggest you the right XML namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me

```
String mess = getResources().getString(R.string.mess_1);
```

More information on [string resources](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#stringresources).